# how to force linux to accept packet with loopback ip

Tags: iptables, tcp, linux-networking, ping, loopback

i have an embedded system with an Ethernet interface that needs to accept external packets with IP of 127.x.x.xx.  is there a way to force Linux to accept external packets with this loop back address and to treat the packets as "normal" IP packets?
also, is there a way to force Linux to send out ping packets when the interface has an IP of 127.x.x.x?

thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "accept" (accept on IP layer or accept for TCP/UDP connections). It might also be helpful to show the actual use case where you have this problem.

Comment: Your are probably barking up the wrong tree. Please clarify your use case.

Comment: hi, sorry for not being clear. when external packet is an arp packe with source ip of 127.x.x.x, kernel drops the packet, not forwarding it up to tcp/ip stack. i traced arp.c inside kernel source and do see that kernel doesn't push the packet up the stack. i understand that this isn't a valid setup but it's an embeded system and my system is required to process all packets. wondering if there's a rule that can force kernel not to drop arp packets with ip of 127.x.x.x  thank you..

Comment: @mark From RFC 1812 : * Internal host loopback address.  Addresses of this form MUST NOT appear outside a host.*

Answer (score 1):

Linux has a weak [host model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model) and the network stack doesn't really care which interface an TCP/IP packet arrives on. If it is for a configured IP-address it will be accepted.

That does not take into account ARP, firewall rules and routing.

Comment: hi Hbrujin, i noticed that the kernel doesn't route arp packet with 127.x.x.x. kerel will discard packet. is there a rule that will make kernel route arp packet with ip of 127.x.x.x? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From **[RFC 1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812)** :

> (e) { 127,  }

```
     Internal host loopback address.  Addresses of this form MUST
     NOT appear outside a host.
```

The kernel uses `net.ipv4.conf.<interface>.route_localnet` to make 127.0.0.0/8 routable or not (actually consider source/destination IP addresses of this kind as martian packets or not).

I completely disencourage you to to play with this, you **MUST** rethink your setup.

Comment: hi xavier, unforutnately, the packets that are coming into my interface is out of my control and i can not change the ip....these packets come from another embeded system...even though this is discoraged, if you have a solution, please let me know. thank you in advance.